# Making an environment local for collection in Postman

Tags: postman

I've seen the postman doc about environments:

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/variables

where an image expresses that the enviornments are local to a collection, which I'm not seeing that happens in my Postman.

[image: Postman image from doc]

I have many projects, each one with its collecion, and I want to set the different environment urls for each project. However, I'm seeing that the environments are shared through all the collections. How can I make the environments local to a collection?

Thank you!

Comment: If you select edit on the collection folder, you can set variables in there. This can then be called in the scripts by using `pm.variables.get('var_name')` - If that's what you mean?

Comment: Not really. I wanted to set different environment variable values for each collection. For example, in all my projects I have 'development', 'staging' and 'production' environments each with the corresponding 'url' variable. This url depends on the project, so sharing the environment among all the collections is not what I want.

Comment: I created a HTTP testing tool that organizes environments inside collections. It is compatible with Postman collections and environments.
https://github.com/alexandrehtrb/Pororoca

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The picture that you posted actually defines as to how the variables are resolved.
You can have different types of variables.

Which are:

- Global Variables
- Environment Variables
- Collection Variables
- Local Variables
- Variables from data

Suppose you have a variable 'a' with a value 5 defined as a global variable.
But you also have a **collection variable** 'a' with value '7' 
So, when you're sending the request, the order in which the variables will be resolved is what the picture tells you.

Globals > Collection > Environment > Local > Data
 - That's the order of resolution.

So, that'll be done like so:

Globals (a = 5) > Collection (a = 7) > Environment (a not defined) > Local (a not defined) > Data (a not defined)

So, the final value of 'a' after going through the resolution order would come out to be **7**

Environment variables are available to all the collections in a **Workspace** 
Each environment is specific to the workspace.
So are the globals.

If you want to use variables only specific to each collection then you need to use the **Collection Variables**

To add collection variables, just go to the sidebar and hover on the collection you want to add the variables for and click '●●●'

Then click 'Edit' > 'Variables' > Add the variables that you want only specific to this collection.

[image: Postman Edit Collection]

Now in the Request you can use these variables just in a similar fashion as you use the other variables.
For eg.: *https://**{{url}}**/get?foo=bar*

or in a test script:

```
console.log(pm.variables.get('car'));  // 'astonMartin'
```

Postman will do the rest for you.

Environment variables come handy when you have different environments such as PROD, STAGING, BETA etc. Many people use them like so.
Otherwise, they're just variables so use it as you like.

Alternatively, if you want to use an environment for a few collections and another environment for another one.
Then create multiple **Workspaces** and add collections to it with the corresponding environment. Finally, switch between these workspaces as per the need.

Comment: Thank you. So in the end, it's not possible to define different environments for the different collections. It should be possible, though. Very often people use only one workspace and a collection for each project, which should have different environment variables. 
Isn't it possible to create the environments PROD, STAGING,etc. and set the value of the variable 'url' to reference a collection variable like {{url-staging}} ?

Comment: But why doesn't the 'Collection Variable' solve this for you? It aims to exactly fit your use case just that you can't name it like 'C1 Variables' or 'PROD' and have different variables as per the different stage of development.

Comment: You can also specifically access environment variables with the api: `pm.environment.get` and set them with the `pm.environment.set` function. 
Then you can specify conditions like if a variable let's say 'STAGE' in the collection says 'PROD' then use all the PROD environment variables. 
You can make something like that. :)
But really, switching environments isn't tough either. 
Given at any point of time, you'll be using 1 collection and 1 request to work upon. 
Also, if you're using collection runner then also you'd be using only 1 collection and 1 environment for the run.

Comment: Additionally: `pm.globals.get` and `pm.globals.get` API is also available.

Comment: The collection variables would require me to use {{url-staging}}, {{url-production}} instead of just using {{url}} and chaging the value of the url depending on the environment. Right?

Comment: The other solution you gave fixes what I wanted. I was just hoping I could do that more easily. Thank you!!

Comment: Yes you can do that with the variables! Perfect!

Comment: I was stumbling accross this. Which solution did you end up with @LeticiaEsperon? Maybe you could create an answer for that.

Comment: TBH, I don't remember! @Tschenser I believe the accepted answer but not sure

Comment: But collection variables are not secret, especially when you export it.

Comment: @SivcanSingh if I want to have set of env variables like dev prod etc for one collection. The only way is workspaces, right? I can't do collection variable: 1. Because I have multiple profiles like dev prod 2. I have secrets

Comment: @ar-siddiqui That's correct, you'd need multiple environments for your collection within a workspace, where each environment holds different values for each of the variables based on dev/prod/etc.

Comment: Thanks. This clarified how I was using Environments wrong. I build APIs for different projects and  each project has different settings that I want to reuse in requests, but only for a specific API. The environment option was not the appropriate solution. The Collection variables were better, even though I have to recreate them for each API.

Answer (score 12):

Or maybe just abandon environment feature of postman, and simplify and use only Pre-req script and `{{URL}}` in methods, just repeat for every collection:

```
const ENVIRONMENTS = {
    DEV: {
        name: "development", 
        url: "http://localhost:3000"
    }, 
    STAGE : {
        name: "staging", 
        url: "..."
    }, 
    PROD : {
        name: "production", 
        url: "..."
    } 
};
pm.collectionVariables.set("URL", (ENVIRONMENTS.DEV).url);
```

Or maybe... use environment feature of Postman just for setting environment variable  .
Then read that variable in every collection pre-request script just choose environment:

```
...

envName = pm.environment.get('Environment')
const selected = ENVIRONMENTS[envName]

pm.collectionVariables.set("URL", selected.url);
pm.collectionVariables.set("Token", selected.token);
```

Comment: Great solution.  I ended up wiping out a dozen environment and saved all the exporting hassle.

Comment: While I like this approach, the biggest issue with us come down to sensitive data. I would not want to hardcode a secret key into the pre-request script. Where as Environments allow you to hide sensitive data.

Answer (score 8):

I found my way here with the same question, and came up with a way to fake it. My goal was to be able to easily export a collection without also exporting my whole set of environment variables (including those for other projects) to support it.

Basically you create a proxy variable for each set of environment specific values you want to have in the collection.

**First**, edit your collection and use the pre-request script to set the environment name as an environment variable. I thought there might be a built in variable for this, but didn't find one.

```
pm.environment.set("envName", pm.environment.name)
```

[image: pre-request script screenshot]

**Next**, use that variable in a new collection variable that acts as a kind of proxy to a matching variable with the environment specific value. Alternatively you could create the proxy variable in the pre-request script too.

```
{{url}} -> {{{{envName}}-url}} -> {{ee-url}} -> your url for ee environment
                               -> {{pr-url}} -> your url for pr environment
```

[image: collection variables screenshot]

**Finally**, you can use the proxy variable as normal.

```
{{url}}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, thanks for sharing, but what a rigmarole.